# how to validate input in Composers' askAndValidate function

Tags: php, composer-php

Hey Guys i have been wrecking the Internet trying to find some clue || example || the likes.

I'm trying to run a composer post-install-cmd script

my current code -

```
namespace Core\Scripts;
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
use Composer\Script\Event;
use Composer\Console\HtmlOutputFormatter;


class installer {
   public static function install(Event $event){

    $callback = (function($arg){
        if(is_dir($arg)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });

    $composer = $event->getComposer();
    $IO = $event->getIO();
    $currentDir = getcwd();

    $resp = $IO->ask('Is `'.$currentDir.'` the path to project root? :', true);
    var_dump($resp);
    if($resp === false || strtolower($resp) === 'no'){
        $resp2 = $IO->askAndValidate('Please enter the path to project root :', $callback ,3);
        define('_pROOT', $resp2);
    }else{
        define('_pROOT', $currentDir);
    }
    print_r(_pROOT);

  }

}
```

Here i'm trying to get the user input from the console and validate it. The code executes correctly upto the `$callback` function. But with in the callback function on `return false`,
instead of looping back to the question it just stops execution.

**So my question would be -**

1. what do i return if not false if the argument does not meet my validation requirements.
2. Also another think i would like assistance with is figuring out how to give color to the output(which is currently at default console white), as i want my questions to be green in color.
   PS - i did find the `HtmlOutputFormatter` class but couldn't figure how to use it to change color. And i know there are the composer api docs, but that doesn't help.

Please can someone/anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Following https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/IO/IOInterface.html#method_askAndValidate you should throw an \Exception whenever the validation shall fail. Otherwise return the data from user input.
I suppose you could alter them, but that should be handled after the validation, outside of the callback.